# Angular.js not found, but no error on link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I picked up Angular.js yesterday as part of an internship, and Node.js the day before, so I'm a complete beginner with these technologies.

Basically, I tried to make a really simple page with an input field which would print the input text right next to the field, like [such](https://jsfiddle.net/r2q3c52z/). As you can see, it works in a jsfiddle.

But when I try this locally, I get a ReferrenceError at the angular.module call of my controller, and [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp) in my browser.

Here's my index.html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input ng-model="query"/>
        <span><b ng-bind="queryResult()"></b></span>
    </div>



    <!-- Scripts et liens css.-->
    <script src="./controller.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
</body>
```

And my controller.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.query = "";
    $scope.queryResult = function(){
        return $scope.query;
    };
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you including twice jquery in your index.html ? You also need to include your controller after angularJS

Comment: A couple other issues aside from what was included in the answer below: 1) That `<div>` tag above the `<head>` section. 2) `ng-app` should probably be affixed to `<body>` instead. 3) Your CSS should go in your head section. 4) You're including angular, jQuery, and bootstrap multiple times.

Comment: It also looks like you're embedding angular twice (once from a CDN, once as a bower component.)   Meanwhile, consider omitting jQuery altogether, especially while you're learning Angular; angular's own jqlite is nearly always sufficient.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was apparently the order, as was said in the answer and comments. I feel like an idiot. As per the double includes, I got the includes from another similar file, and must have messed up the copy/paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should include

```
<script src="./controller.js"></script>
```

after angular js files

Answer (score 0):

The order of your controller file and AngularJS CDN is the problem. Please add your JS file beneath AngularJS CDN.

And also You have added ng-app to a div which does not have a closing tag. It might cause problems too.

Try the following code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input ng-model="query"/>
        <span><b ng-bind="queryResult()"></b></span>
    </div>



    <!-- Scripts et liens css.-->
    <script src="./controller.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are including jQuery after angular. jQuery should be first.

It also looks like you are including angular twice.

angular.min.js and angular.js